# How do I get rid of burn marks in my pots?

Tags: cleaning, pot, stainless-steel

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can brown stains be removed from pots and pans?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2880/60)
>   [How to keep my stainless steel skillet clean?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5841/60)

A couple of times I've left things cooking a drop too long - and all the water evaporated and the food started to burn. Once it was potatoes; once apples. Both times I caught it pretty quickly and most of it came off, but now I'm left with slight scorch marks on the bottom and one of the sides of my pot - small burnt-looking black patches. Is there anything to do to get rid of them? (The pot is made of stainless steel.) I've tried cooking water and dishwashing soap in the pot, but it didn't really help. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make a paste of baking soda and scrub with a green scrubby pad. Also The Pampered Chef sells a stainless cleaner that works great on all stainless pans. (In the interest of full disclosure, I am a Pampered Chef Consultant and use it on my pans all the time)